# issue with IPV6 network on iOS submission

Tags: ios, cordova, ipv6

I have developed an iOS app in cordova, but this app was rejected due to some IPV6 network issue.

Error message

> All apps are reviewed on an IPv6 network. While the issue we
>   encountered during review might not be caused specifically by IPv6
>   incompatibility, it is important to make sure your app can run on an
>   IPv6-only network. Supporting IPv6-only Networks gives details on
>   supporting IPv6-only networks. You can also find answers to commonly
>   asked questions regarding IPv6-only compatibility on Apple Developer
>   Forums’ Supporting IPv6-only Networks Q&A page. Step-by-step
>   instructions for setting up a local IPv6 network on your Mac can be
>   found in Supporting IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks.

I'm facing this issue since long and cannot get through a proper solution for it.
Tried removing the network checking plugins and also tried deactivating all the other suspected plugins, but all in vain.

I have installed the following plugins:

> cordova-plugin-facebook4, cordova-plugin-google-analytics,
>   cordova-plugin-inappbrowser, cordova-plugin-network-information,
>   cordova-plugin-whitelist, cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing,
>   cordova-plugin-x-toast, phonegap-plugin-push

And I stuck at a blind end now.

Comment: Are you testing your application on an IPv6-only network per Apple's instructions?

Comment: I am working on IPV4 network.

Comment: If you never test it the way Apple does, how do you expect it to pass? You can easily follow the simple apple instructions to create the test network.